# Cannot distinguish single character words with libunibreak

Tags: c, unicode, line-breaks

When I use `set_word_breaks_utf32()` from the libunibreak library to navigate through words, I see that single letter words (i.e. 'a' in English, '北' in Chinese, ...) disappear because they always evaluate to WORDBREAK_BREAK and are consequently indistinguishable from surrounding whitespace.  The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wordbreak.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    uint32_t text[] = { 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '.', '\n' };
    char breaks[1024];
    size_t length = sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]);
    set_word_breaks_utf32(text, length, "", breaks);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) putchar(text[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) putchar(breaks[i] + '0');
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code shows clearly that the letter 'a' is indistinguishable from the surrounding whitespace:

```
This is a test.
1110010000111000
```

What can I do to ensure that the boundaries of single letter words are distinguishable in `set_word_breaks_utf32()` output?

[Apologies for using the `line-breaks` tag, but the `word-break` tag is related to a CSS property.]

Comment: why it is the problem?

Comment: @Lashane I need to be able to navigate through a text field a word at a time, and single letter words are currently being skipped entirely because I never see a transition from `WORDBREAK_NOBREAK` to `WORDBREAK_BREAK`.

Comment: why do you use word break information to navigate through words?

Comment: @Lashane I'm using libunibreak because it implements the algorithm described in Unicode Standard Annex 14 and Unicode Standard Annex 29.  That allows me to identify word boundaries even in complex foreign scripts where I can't simply look for whitespace or punctuation.  How would you propose that I navigate through words other than using word break information?

Comment: to navigate between words you need to find word delimiters, not line breaks

Comment: @Lashane Please re-read the question.  I explained my problem and provided code to demonstrate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127842/discussion-between-josh-sanford-and-lashane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-25.html#Default_Word_Boundaries) isn't really designed for that. What `set_wordbreaks_utf32()` does is find each *word boundary*.

```
This is a test.
1110010000111000

  T   h   i   s  ' '  i   s  ' '  a  ' '  t   e   s   t   .  '\n'
|   _   _   _   |   |   _   |   |   |   |   _   _   _   |   |    |
```

Each `|` above is a word boundary, which can be helpful to find words, but is not the complete solution. Note that there is an implicit word boundary at the beginning of the string. A complete word detection algorithm will have to determine if a character between each adjacent word boundary is a unicode letter, and mark that character as a word accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It certainly appears to me that Annex #29 is intended for word navigation based on Section 4 of the document:  "Word boundaries are used in a number of different contexts.  The most familiar ones are selection (double-click mouse selection or 'move to next word' control-arrow keys) ..."  Were you perhaps trying to say that `set_word_breaks_utf32()` isn't designed for that?  But your explanation of the output was very helpful, as was your explanation that I have to check characters between adjacent word boundaries.  Do you know whether libunibreak can help with that?

Comment: I see that libunibreak has internal function `get_char_wb_class()` which can be used with the internal `wb_prop_default` table.  I wonder why that function or something similar is not exposed to the user, since it would seem to provide the other half of the functionality I need.

Comment: I copied `get_char_wb_class()` and `wb_prop_default` and wrapped the adjacent word boundary logic into my existing code.  Word navigation now behaves correctly.